# RAII with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, raii

I want to initialize two instances of a classes through smart pointers:

```
    std::shared_ptr< myQueue > _pA ;
    std::shared_ptr< myQueue > _pB ;

    _pA.reset( new myQueue() ) ;
    _pB.reset( new myQueue() ) ;
```

Do I have initialized with the above reset function two different myQueues or just two pointers on the same object?

Comment: Think about how many instance of `myQueue` you have above, hint: `new myQueue()` constructs a *new instance*... If you want the shared pointers to *point to the same instance*, construct one and then assign the pointer to the second pointer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your myQueue class isn't weird, yes, you will have two separate instances.

You might also be interested in  [`make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), which would let you write it like this:

```
auto _pA = std::make_shared<myQueue>();
auto _pB = std::make_shared<myQueue>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I will check on this!

Comment: +1 - `make_shared` is the preferred way to make a shared pointer, as it puts the object and reference count in a single allocation.

Comment: @Chad Or not; I don't think that this is guaranteed.  The important thing is that it puts the `new` and the construction of the `shared_ptr` in a single function call, so they can't be reordered with something else that might through.  In particular, something like `f( std::make_shared<MyQueue>(), std::make_shared<MyQueue>() )` is legal, and doesn't risk leaking memory.  (Of course, realistically, functions taking a `shared_ptr` should be pretty scarce.)

Comment: You are correct, it's not guaranteed by the standard.  Agreed, there are also other (very good) reasons to prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Initializing the two `shared_ptr` with two pointers to the same object will result in a double delete.  You don't *ever* want to do it.